# jQuery UI datepicker: getDate to prepend the selected date?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have my UI datepicker, and tried onSelect to prepend the date you have chosen inside #viewCalender:

```
        $(function() {
    $('#rangeA').daterangepicker({
        arrows: true, 
        onClose: function(event) {
            $('#calenderView').prepend('Ok!');
        },
        onSelect:
         function(){
            var day1 = $("#rangeA").datepicker('getDate').getDate();                  
            var month1 = $("#rangeA").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;             
            var year1 = $("#rangeA").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
            var fullDate = year1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + day1;
             $('#calenderView').prepend(fullDate);
            }
    });
});
```

But nothing happens when I select a date. What is wrong here?

```
    onClose:
     function(){

        var date = $(".range-start").datepicker('getDate');
        var dateEnd = $(".range-end").datepicker('getDate');
        if(date != null){
            if(dateEnd != null){
            var day2 = dateEnd.getDate();
            var month2 = dateEnd.getDate();
            var year2 = dateEnd.getDate();
            var fullDate2 = year2 + "-" + month2 + "-" + day2;
            }else{
            var fullDate2 = 0;
            }
        var day1 = date.getDate();                  
        var month1 = date.getMonth() + 1;             
        var year1 = date.getFullYear();
        var fullDate = year1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + day1;
        $.ajax({
        url: "misc/getCalender.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { dateStart: fullDate, dateEnd: fullDate2 },
        success: function(response){
        alert('passed: ' + fullDate + ' - '+ fullDate2);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `onSelect`, [the event is `onChange`](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker_v2/js/daterangepicker.jQuery.js), just change your code to use that option and you should be all set.  Also, the date isn't stored in `#rangeA` but another set of inputs it creates, `.range-start` and `.range-end` respectively (yes...you can't have more than one on a page currently).

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/P3qw3/), note that `onChange` also fires twice per selection...this shouldn't be a problem when you're using the result to replace a value, instead of prepending it (resulting in multiple prepends).

Comment: I didnt use onChange, exactly because of that it fires twice per selection. So instead I would like to use onClose, and check if a date is in date.getDate(), and then if there is, prepend the getdate(pass the date in a ajax request)..

Comment: @Johnson - You simply can't use `onSelect`, it's not an option you can override, you can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/P3qw3/2/

Comment: @NickCraver If I would like to pass the date in a ajax request, onChange, then it would pass it like: 2010-11-162010-11-16 (twice as you may know) if I choose one of the top options(today, 7days ago, previous month)? How would I then solve that?

Comment: @Johnson - why are you prepending it? why not just *set* the value to something?

Comment: @NickCraver because I want to know what I am going to set into the variable that are going to pass

Comment: @NickCraver please see my updated question. It execute the ajax call twice, and thats why I dont wanted to use onChange

Comment: Ok, im on my way although, when I select last 7 days (9/11/2010 - 16/11/2010) it only passes 9/11/2010, and i need both dates in order to check last 7 days in the db on the requested page..

Comment: @Johnson - the other date is `.range-end`

Comment: @NickCraver ok, when i use onChange the arrow buttons doesnt activate the ajaxcall

Answer (score 0):

Using http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/ as the docs for this plugin, I don't see any use of onSelect, except for in the comments.  It seems like you should put that onSelect code in the onClose function, which would get fired when a date is selected.